# AngularJS + Rails + Devise - Logout issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I am making a AngularJS app using Rails as the API and Devise gem for Authentication.

Currently in my rails home controller I am doing:

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
    set_csrf_cookie_for_angular
    render Rails.root.join('public', 'angular_app').to_s, layout: false
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Basically if a user is signed in go to the "angular_app" which is actually a renamed index.html file, else go to the devise sign in form.

This works great as I can just do

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

for all pages that require login, and I can handle the 401's from a Angular interceptor.

Now the problem I am having is redirecting the user to the sign in page from Angular

```
.config(function ($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
        var interceptor = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$q', function($location, $rootScope, $q) {
            function success(response) {
              return response;
            };

            function error(response) {
                if (response.status == 401) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unauthorized');
                    $location.path('/users/sign_in');
                };
            };

            return function(promise) {
                return promise.then(success, error);
            };
        }];
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
  })
```

The location.path changes the URL to the right path - but won't show me the form until I manually refresh the page. Looking through the console on a refresh it does a GET and then loads the page. Is there a way I can mimic this in angular?

If anyone has a better way of handling this please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the browser refresh with `$window.location.href = '/users/sign_in'`